# How to show info about page number between "previous" and "next" buttons in DataTables?

Tags: javascript, css, datatables, pagination

I need to show text about the current page number and total page count between 'previous/next' buttons in the DataTable table [this is how it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGtQb.png). I made pagingType: "simple", but I do not know how to put text between those two buttons.

Comment: Are you using jquery DataTable?

Comment: Yes, jQuery DataTable

Answer (score 0):

The following approach will give you a basic layout which matches your request - but **you may need to provide additional styling** to achieve the look and feel you may want.

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {
    
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
      "pagingType": "full",
      "language": {
        "info": "_START_ of _TOTAL_",
        "paginate": {
          "first":      "",
          "last":       "",
          "next":       ">",
          "previous":   "<"
        }
      } ,
      "initComplete": function() {
        tabulate(this.api().page.info());
      }
    });

    table.on( 'draw', function () {
      tabulate(table.page.info());
    } );

  } );

  function tabulate(pageInfo) {
    var curr = pageInfo.page + 1;
    var tot = pageInfo.pages;
    $( "<span>" + curr + " of " + tot + "</span>" ).insertAfter( "a.paginate_button.previous" );
  }
  
</script>
```

Using the default DataTables styling, this displays as follows:

[image]

And the "next" and "previous" arrows are highlighted on mouseover if there are more pages in the related direction:

[image]

*Notes on the code:*

We replace the standard [pagination language](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language) with customizations, for our needs.

We use `initComplete` with an [api callback](https://datatables.net/examples/api/api_in_init) to handle the initial display of our custom pagination display, and a `draw()` event function for subsequent changes.

The `tabulate()` function uses [`page.info()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/page.info()) data to get the required numbers.